# How to find the highest and lowest number with JS?

Tags: javascript, numbers

I would like to know why my code isn't working.
There are different ways to solve this issue using `Math.max()` and `Math.min()`, however I do not want any other method for this stage as I'm still learning iterations.

Could anyone tell me why this isn't working as I intended? I want to get the highest number and the lowest number from a string, when I run it:

```
highAndLow("4 5 29 54 4 0 -1 -3209093 -214 -542 -64 -1 -3 -6"); // The result of this is 54 and -3209093 

highAndLow("1 1"); // The result of this is 1 and 0
```

So as you can see the result for the second try should be 1 and 1 but it gives me 1 and 0.

What did I do wrong here?

```
function highAndLow(numbers){
    var num;
    var maxNum = 0;
    var minNum =0;
    num = numbers.split(" ").map(Number);

    num.map( function(el){
        if(el >= maxNum) {
            maxNum = el;
        }
        if(el <= minNum) {
            minNum = el;
        }
    });
    console.log(maxNum + ' ' + minNum);
}
highAndLow("4 5 29 54 4 0 -1 -3209093 -214 -542 -64 -1 -3  -6"); **// The result of this is 54 and -3209093**
highAndLow("1 1"); **// The result of this is 1 and 0**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```js
let arr = [0, 2, 45, 23];

let min = arr.reduce((prev, curr) => Math.min(prev, curr), Number.MAX_VALUE);

let max = arr.reduce((prev, curr) => Math.max(prev, curr), Number.MIN_VALUE);

console.log(min, max);
```

It goes through every value, and looks if it's higher than the current highest (or lower than the current lowest). For more information on `reduce()`, look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Also look at the answer by @Mario Perez for a slightly more elegant solution

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) However I really wish to learn my code before I move onto Math.max/Math.min... Could you please tell me what was wrong with my code?

Comment: If it worked, please accept the answer. This indicates it worked for you and answered your question. To accept, click the check mark on the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = [0, 100, 2, 45, 23, 1.5, 45.5];

let min = Math.min(...arr)
let max = Math.max(...arr)

console.log(min)
console.log(max)
```

Hi, you could use the Math object to obtain min and max values spreading the array as shown above.

Comment: Didn't think of this, very elegant

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment! however I really wish to understand why my code isn't working here... if you know could you please tell me what was wrong??

Comment: For one, `map` isn't what you're looking for. You'd want `forEach` or `reduce`. Also, by starting off the values at 0, you might not get the right answers. Start the max value at `Number.MIN_VALUE` and the min at `Number.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: to add on @AlexH, remember that some methods return new values ( like map ) and others dont (like forEach) this helps me a lot when choosing the correct implementation

Comment: you can write ```Math.min(...arr)```; instead of ```Math.min(...[...arr])``` just for short )

Comment: Thanks @WillBlack for some reason it didn't work in codepen when I wrote it like that the first time, I've edited the answer to reflect your input.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you initialize *minNum* to zero, zero is less than one. That's why the result is 1 and 0.